# Ubuntu running slowly after installation and also hangs 

Tags: 12.04, performance

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on my machine alongside Windows 7.
After that, Ubuntu runs slowly on my system and sometimes it hangs. What could be the problem?

System specification:

**Memory**: 1 GB RAM
**Hard disk:** 250 GB
**Processor:**: Intel core 2 duo (2.53 GHz)
**Graphics card:** 256 MB Intel integrated graphic card
**Motherboard:** Intel DG31PR chipset

[My system information](http://paste.ubuntu.com/988519/) is given.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/988519/

Comment: i pasted my syslog content here..

Answer (score 3):

after alot of research i got that it was unity that was causing prob.. atleast for me.. unity 2d 0r 3d it was making it slow.. now i am using cairo dock.. its light and hassle free.. no more issues of slow experience... everything else rox on ubuntu... wish all the games also supported linux.. so that u dont had to switch btwn windows n linux to play them... hope the day will arrive soon when i'll be playin nfs n all that stuff on linux.. :)

Comment: You can install NFS on Linux with PlayOnLinux (WINE).

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion it might be due too little RAM. Try to install LUbuntu (if possible) and chceck if it behaves the same. Other reason might be using Ubuntu 3D Unity when Your PC has not enough resources (VGA driver might be not working, or VGA is hasn't got enough performance)

Regards

Comment: how to use unity 2d apart from selecting it every time i log in.. isnt there a permanent setting??

Comment: Well, I've noticed that after choosing it once I have Unity2D as default.

Comment: i didnt knew it.. thanx.. unity2d made it a bit faster..

Answer (score 1):

How much swap memory have you installed , or try gnome fall-back mode [ You will have to install gnome-shell  for that ].
 Also try gnome-classic and Unity 2D.

Comment: sansan@ubuntu:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           983        866        117          0        100        264
-/+ buffers/cache:        501        481
Swap:          255        180         75

Comment: Filename                       Type Size  Used   Priority /host/ubuntu/disks/swap.disk   file 262140 181364 -1

Comment: @sandy- You should try gnome Classic , cinnamon , or mate. Though not a great difference in resources usage but usable.

For cinnamon 
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cinnamon

For classic GNOME

sudo apt-get install gnome-panel 

I would recommend you to try all of the above.And post your conclusions.

Or alternate way is installing Lubuntu or Linux Mint 12 LXDE here http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=1937